# I am looking for the author of a trilogy

Tags: story-identification, books

Okay, so this is going to be vague, but I read a scifi series (there were 3 books total) that takes place in the future, each book is from the point of view of a different character (all boys).  In the first book the boy is taken and trained like sort of a ninja; in the second, the boy is from a rich family and he gets kidnapped or runs away; and the third is about a boy who is a spy and it has slight homoerotic connotations.

If anyone know what books these are that would be fantastic!
Thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know what "m/m" means?

Comment: @Kyralessa: I'm guessing male/male homoerotic.

Comment: I'm 99% sure I can construct a valid answer out of Harry Potter fanfics... :)

Comment: Aaaand user has been deleted..?

Comment: Related [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2812/1027).